# How to display the correct unit of measure in PyQgis?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Within a plugin I am developing I select features and for each line feature selected I get the feature distance using:

```
distance.measureLength(feature.geometry())
```

I also get the total length at the end using:

```
totallength = totallength + distance.measureLength(feature.geometry())
```

I display the total length in a message box but I don't know how to get the correct units of measure using pyqgis.  How do I know if I should use feet or meters?

I tried using:

```
distance.lengthUnits()
```

but that returns a value of 6.  Why?

Answer (score 4):

The distance object you have is a `QgsDistanceArea`.

If you have a look at the [docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDistanceArea.html#abce86a368fff8ffb4507a57d70dcb262), the `distance.lengthUnits()` method returns a `QgsUnitTypes.DistanceUnit` code. [QgsUnitTypes.DistanceUnit](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsUnitTypes.html#a0602e8a06afd37c267e9e532bb27f50d) is an enum, that is, it has codes for each of its values.

You can get the value corresponding to certain code, i.e., the display string for the units in this way:

```
QgsUnitTypes.toString(6)  # degrees
```

You'll get the same using this recommended way:

```
QgsUnitTypes.toString(distance.lengthUnits())  # degrees
```

Of course, you can also find the method `toString()` in the [docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsUnitTypes.html#a43808dc6ed58c191cc4373e7c8e506fb).

---

**NOTE**: You can tell the `QgsDistanceArea` object the CRS you want to use.

If you have the EPSG code, do something like this:

```
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2272, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
d.setSourceCrs(crs, QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
```

If you have a layer object with a CRS set, do something like this:

```
d.setSourceCrs(layer.sourceCrs(), QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
```

Next time you ask for length units, you'll get those defined in the CRS you passed to the `QgsDistanceArea`.

Comment: Why would it return 6 (degrees) as the units?  My the project and shapefile are using EPSG:2272.

Comment: That's another question. I updated the answer with some notes regarding units of a layer.